# Magento 1.9.1 Blank checkout/onepage/success after purchase virtual and/or downloadable products

Tags: error, ce-1.9.1.0

I'm using `Magento ver 1.9.1` `checkout/onepage/success`  gives a blank page without errors after confirming purchase virtual products and/or downloadable products. I can see the order in the backend.

After purchasing simple products the success page gives a normal confirmation and redirect.

Unfortunately I am not able to solve this. Can anyone help please? Thanks!

Ok, this is what I found out:

I use a third party extension.

This is in the config.xml:

```
    <events>        
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_marketplace>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Medma_MarketPlace_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>notifyVendor</method>
                </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_marketplace>
            </observers>
```

This is in the Observer.php:

```
public function notifyVendor($observer)
{       
    $orderIncrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
    $orderObject = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);     

    $vars['billing_address'] = $orderObject->getBillingAddress()->format('html');
    $vars['shipping_address'] = $orderObject->getShippingAddress()->format('html');
    $vars['get_is_not_virtual'] = $orderObject->getIsNotVirtual();
    $vars['customer_name'] = $orderObject->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    $vars['order_no'] = $orderIncrementId;      

    $head = '<thead style="background:#f9f9f9;">
        <tr>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size: 13px; padding: 3px 9px;"><strong>Product</strong></th>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size: 13px; padding: 3px 9px;"><strong><span>Original Price</span></strong></th>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size: 13px; padding: 3px 9px;"><strong>Price</strong></th>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size: 13px; padding: 3px 9px;"><strong>Qty</strong></th>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size: 13px; padding: 3px 9px;"><strong><span>Row Total</strong></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>';

    $orderItems = $orderObject->getAllItems();
    $orderDetails = array();
    foreach($orderItems as $item)
    {
        $attribute = '';
        if($options = $item->getProductOptions())
        {
            if(isset($options['attributes_info']))
            {
                foreach ($options['attributes_info'] as $option)
                    $attribute .='<div><strong>' . $option['label'] . ':</strong> ' . $option['value'] . '</div>';
            }
        }
```

My questions are:

```
    $vars['get_is_not_virtual'] = $orderObject->getIsNotVirtual();
```

causing the blank success page?

How can I solve this? Please help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using the Magento default theme?

Comment: No Smartwave Porto

Comment: I already searched their forum without success.

Comment: Check your server logs for a PHP error, it is the most probable cause of your issue.

Comment: Error is solved.

Comment: add the solution so other users will get help to resolve.